# What is the $ord_P$ function associated to $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, valuation-theory, function-fields

I am busy studying Rosen's "Number Theory in Function Fields" Chapter 5. In this chapter Rosen defines a prime $M$ in the function field $K$ over $F$ to be a discrete valuation ring $R$ with maximal ideal $M$ such that $F\subset R$ and $R/M$ is isomorphic to  $K$. He then states that $\mathsf{ord}_M(*)$ denote the ord function associated with $R$.

I know that for integers a given prime number $p$ we define $\mathsf{ord}_p(a)$ to be the largest number $n$ such that $a\equiv 0 \mod(p^n)$. Is there a similar definition for this $\mathsf{ord}_M(*)$ function that Rosen mentions?

Comment: In the context of function field, that is $K$ is a finite extension of $F(x)$, we require that $F\subset R$ and that $R$ is a DVR. This implies that $R/M$ is a finite extension of $F$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when Rosen says the "quotient field" of $R$ is $K$, he means its field of fractions, not the residue field $R/M$. So every element of $K$ can be written as $a/b$ with $a,b \in R$.

The definition of $\newcommand{\ord}{\operatorname{ord}} \ord_M$ is really quite close to the definition for prime numbers that you've given. Since $R$ is a DVR, then $M$ is principal, so $M = (t)$ for some $t \in R$. Given $r \in R \setminus \{0\}$, then we can write $r = u t^e$ for some unit $u \in R^\times$ and some $e \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. We define $\ord_M(r) = e$ and extend the definition to $K \setminus \{0\}$ by letting $\ord_M(a/b) = \ord_M(a) - \ord_M(b)$.

This agrees with the definition for prime numbers you gave, since if $r = u t^e$ as above, then $r \equiv 0 \pmod{t^e}$, and this is the largest such nonnegative integer $e$. As an aside, if you don't want to choose a uniformizer $t$, $\ord_M(r)$ can be equivalently defined as the largest $e \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ such that $r \in M^e$, where we take $M^0 = R$.

Comment: Thank you for your response that was a very clear and helpful answer.

Comment: Does such a DVR always exist for any field or are there other conditions

Comment: Not for *any* field (take $\mathbb{F}_2$, for instance), but it is always the case in Rosen's setup, where $K$ is a function field in one variable. Let $x \in K$ be transcendental over $F$ so $K$ is a finite extension of the rational function field $F(x)$. If $K$ is separable, then $K = F(x)(y)$ by the Primitive Element Theorem and $y$ is algebraic over $F(x)$. Let $p \in F(x)[T]$ be the minimal polynomial of $y$. Clearing denominators, we can assume that $p \in F[x][T] \cong F[x,T]$. Then $K \cong \frac{F(x)[T]}{p(T)}$ and $O = \frac{F[x][T]}{p(T)} \cong \frac{F[x,T]}{p(x,T)}$ is an order...

Comment: ...contained in $K$. Now if we localize at any maximal ideal $M$ of $O$, we obtain a DVR contained in $K$. For instance, if $p(a,b) = 0$ for some $a,b \in F$, then we can localize at $M = (x-a, y-b)$. For example, the function field $K = \frac{F(x)[y]}{y^2 - (x^3-x)}$ contains the order $O = \frac{F[x][y]}{y^2 - (x^3-x)}$ and $R = O_{(x,y)}$ is such a DVR. The non-separable case is similar, but you may have to adjoin more than one $y$.